# LTSpice - voltage goes through the roof in LC circuit

Tags: oscillator, ltspice, passive-networks

I am trying to simulate an oscillator in LTSpice. 
So I tried to make a simple LC circuit. 
Since a voltage source would not make the circuit oscillate, 
I did not use a voltage source and made the capacitor start with 6 volts. 
But for some reason the voltage just explodes and goes to almost 200kV. 
I have no explanation for this phenomenon. 
Maybe someone can help me with this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxLSl.jpg

Comment: Put realistic DCR in series with L and monitor current and compute energy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand a bit on Tony's comment, LTspice has a default series resistance of 1m\$\Omega\$ for an inductor, so you have an initial current of 6,000A.

Aside from being pretty unrealistic unless the inductor and core were enormous, that means that there is 18,000 J of energy stored in the inductor, so one would expect a peak voltage across the capacitor of about 190,000 V from conservation of energy.